# Specific combinations of Flush and Write calls corrupts BlockBlob used via OpenWrite

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I recently encountered a bug or a least a very strange behavior for BlockBlobs used via `.NET` client.

Basically, specific combination of writes and flushes corrupts a file in a way that if you read it back after writting then the response stream contains garbage (more precisely it is a truncation and
duplication of the last written bytes).

To reproduce (100% chance):

- Assembly Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
- use BlockBlobClient
- use OpenWrite to get a writable stream
- write 4 bytes (all at once or 1 by one)
- call Flush on the stream
- write 2 more bytes (all at once or 1 by one)
- dispose the stream
- read it back why OpenRead
- see that written and read versions are different

Corruption example:

```
var iterations = new List<byte[]?>()
{
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    null,
    new byte[] { 0xFF },
    new byte[] { 0xAA },
};

written: 00000000FFAA
read:        FFAAFFAA
```

Success example:

```
var iterations = new List<byte[]?>()
{
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    null,
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0xFF },
    new byte[] { 0xAA },
};

written: 00000000FFAA
read:    00000000FFAA
```

- `null` is a point at which I call Flush
- content can be any - even all zeros on all iterations
- 0xFF, 0xAA are used only to highligh the duplication

Strangest thing here that if you write 1 more byte after a corruption then the corruption disappears. It only happens if your blob file ends with `write4+flush+write2` sequence.

Did anyone see anything like this?

#### Full Code

```
var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionSting, "test");

var blockBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient($"test{Guid.NewGuid():N}.data");

var iterations = new List<byte[]?>()
{
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new byte[] { 0x00 },
    null,
    new byte[] { 0xFF },
    new byte[] { 0xAA },
};

var writeStream = blockBlobClient.OpenWrite(true, new Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlockBlobOpenWriteOptions()
{
    HttpHeaders = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobHttpHeaders()
    {
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    }
});

var writeMemStream = new MemoryStream();

for (var i = 0; i < iterations.Count; i++)
{
    var buffer = iterations[i];

    if (buffer is null)
    {
        writeStream.Flush();
        writeMemStream.Flush();
    }
    else
    {
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        writeMemStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}

writeStream.Dispose();

var readMemStream = new MemoryStream();
var readStream = blockBlobClient.OpenRead(options: new Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobOpenReadOptions(false)
{
    Position = 0
});
readStream.CopyTo(readMemStream);
readStream.Dispose();

readMemStream.Position = 0;
writeMemStream.Position = 0;
var readArr = readMemStream.ToArray();
var writeArr = writeMemStream.ToArray();

if (!readArr.SequenceEqual(writeArr))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("DIFFERENT");
    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", writeArr.Select(q => q.ToString("X2"))));
    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", readArr.Select(q => q.ToString("X2"))));
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("SAME");
    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", writeArr.Select(q => q.ToString("X2"))));
    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", readArr.Select(q => q.ToString("X2"))));
}
```

Comment: Great work getting this to be reproducible! We have the same issue. Hopefully the GitHub issue (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/20652) gets some traction

Comment: btw, the bug seems to be fixed in 12.9.0-beta.2+ version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is also available in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.8.3

Comment: It will be good if you give the answer directly instead of giving the links. These links may stop working later and the future users can't benefit from that.